# I do not why initialization is needed in this code in java

Tags: java, initialization

I do not know why the initialization of `currentCard` is needed there (where I commented in my code).
Is that statement really needed in this code?

```
  public class Card   {
  private String face;
  private String suit;

  public Card( String cardFace, String cardSuit )
  {
    face = cardFace;
    suit = cardSuit;
  }

  public String toString()
  {
    return face + " of " + suit;
  }
}
```

===============================================================

```
import java.util.Random;

public class DeckOfCards
{
  private Card[] deck;
  private int currentCard;
  private static final int NUMBER_OF_CARDS = 52;
  private static final Random randomNumbers = new Random();

  public DeckOfCards()
  {
    String[] faces = {"Ace", "Deuce", "Three", "Four", 
        "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", 
        "Queen", "King" };
    String[] suits = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"};

    deck = new Card[NUMBER_OF_CARDS];
    currentCard = 0;

    for( int count = 0; count < deck.length; count++)
      deck[ count ] = 
        new Card( faces[ count % 13 ], suits[ count / 13 ] );
  }
  public void shuffle()
  {
    currentCard = 0; // I do not know why initialization is needed

    for( int first = 0; first < deck.length; first++ )
    {
      int second = randomNumbers.nextInt( NUMBER_OF_CARDS );

      Card temp = deck[ first ];
      deck[ first ] = deck[ second ];
      deck[ second ] = temp;
    }
  }
  public Card dealCard()
  {
    if( currentCard < deck.length )
      return deck[ currentCard++ ];
    else
      return null;
  } 
}


public class DeckOfCardsTest
{
  public static void main( String[] args )
  { 
    DeckOfCards myDeckOfCards = new DeckOfCards();
    myDeckOfCards.shuffle();

    for( int i = 1; i <= 52; i++)
    {
      System.out.printf("%-19s", myDeckOfCards.dealCard() );

      if( i % 4 ==0 )
        System.out.println();
    }
  }    
}
```

Comment: what initialization ?

Comment: currentCard = 0; in shuffle method

Comment: @nafas I suspect question is about `currentCard = 0; // I do not know why initialization is needed` line.

Comment: @Pshemo ahh I c mate, it was abit hard to detect

Comment: it is not needed. java initializes primitives by default

Comment: @이현정 this is not a compiler error is it? the compiler should not complain about that line

Comment: It's just what aioobe answered.... shuffle is supposed to reset this value. Obviously the asker did not write this code, he just wanted to know why this line exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `currentCard` says which card to deal next (see `dealCard()` method)
- `shuffle()` does two things: 1) It shuffles the deck, and 2) resets the `currentCard` so that the next card to deal is card 0.

(The `currentCard = 0` is not necessary for the shuffling itself!)